# how to auto hide a button when the ion-content is scrolling and show when scroll stops

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3, scrollview

This is my HTML file where I have used `scroll function` event.

```
<ion-content (ionScroll)="scrollFunction($event)">
    <ion-card *ngFor="let product of products" no-padding>
    <ion-item class="bigclass">
     <ion-thumbnail item-height="100px" item-start>
       <img-loader *ngIf="product.images" src="{{product.images[0].src}}" useImg></img-loader>
     </ion-thumbnail>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadMoreProducts($event)">
     <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll> 
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
    <button class="proceed" *ngIf="isShown" ion-button full (click)="proceedPayment()">Proceed</button>
</ion-footer>
```

this is my `.ts` file. It is hiding the button on scroll down event but not showing. I want it to work when I scroll up or down the "Proceed" button. It should hide and when the scroll of `ion-content` stops then the button should be visible.

```
public isShown:bolean=false;
constructor(public navCtrl:NavController){
    this.WooCommerce.getAsync('products?
      consumer_key=ck&consumer_secret=cs').then((result) => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body));
      this.products = JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
      console.log(this.products);
      this.products.forEach(product => { product.quantity = 1, 
      product.disabled=false;});
      return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);         
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err)  
    })
}

public scrollFunction = (event: any) => {
    let dimensions = this.content.getContentDimensions(); 
    let bottomPosition = dimensions.contentHeight + dimensions.scrollTop; 
    let screenSize = dimensions.scrollHeight;
    this.isShown = screenSize - bottomPosition <= 10 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I think this might be helpful https://pointdeveloper.com/ionic-hide-floating-action-button-fab-scroll/

Comment: Yes I have implemented it but how to do it with ion-button@PareshGami

Comment: Its working fine with fab button 
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("All Transtition set");
    this.fabRef = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("fab")[0];
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.fabRef, 'webkitTransition', 'transform 500ms,top 500ms');
  }
but when I change class from fab to my button class name then its not working at all.Please guide me if you have any idea how to correct it:)
@PareshGami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind following method on `ion-content`

- **ionScrollStart**
- **ionScrollEnd**

  `<ion-content (ionScrollStart)="scrollStart($event)" (ionScrollEnd)="scrollStart($event)`

and handle this event by updating `isShown`

```
  scrollStart(event) {
     this.isShown = false;
   }

  scrollStop(event) {
     this.isShown = true;
  }
```

Comment: I have tried this method but its not working.Using this method the button gets hide on scroll-start but not shown on scroll-stop.@ChintanKukadiya

Comment: then button is not even reacting using this method.

Comment: Hello Kriti, [FIDDLE] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/show-hide-button-on-scroll?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts) 
you have to update `isShown` after pushing more products in `loadMoreProducts` 

`    loadMoreProducts(infiniteScroll){
        setTimeout(() => {
      // Add Products here 
     /* for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        this.products.push( procuct );
      }*/
      infiniteScroll.complete();
      this.isShown = true;
    }, 100, this);
    
  }`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion this is working fine and its great....But still there is one issue and that is  it only works when ion infinite scroll function calls i.e on (ionInfinite) but this function is called very late in my program and I want to work on evey scroll event like on scroll start and scroll stop but [event.complete] property exist in (ionInfinite) event only

Comment: @kritisharma, Okay now i finally done what you want is HERE(https://stackblitz.com/edit/show-hide-button-on-scroll?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts)

Comment: thanks a lot it works exactly the way I want. Thanks for your help .@ChintanKukadiya

Comment: Change - (ionScrollEnd)="scrollStop($event)  for the above answer to work as expected.

Comment: @ChintanKukadiya What in case of don't have enough item to scroll require because not sure how many items come in the scrollable screen.